# Google Apps Script for INDEX/MATCH

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets, both of which have rows with the same ID's.

[image: Internal Audit Register]

[image: SOP Register]

Both sheets have an ID column, column B in the Internal Audit Register, and column A in the SOP Register. When a date is entered into column G of the Internal Audit Register, I want that date pasted/overwritten into column H of the SOP Register where the ID's match. In the same row, I also want column E changed to false and columns F and G cleared.

I have partly written the following onEdit(e) Script but I am struggling with the VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH script.

```js
// Edit SOP Register sheet after Internal Audit completed
 {var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var originsheetname = "Internal Audit Register"
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var column = 7;
  var date = range.getValue();
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]' && editedColumn == column && editedRow > 2 && sheet.getName() == originsheetname) {
    var objectsheetname = "SOP Register";
    var object = e.source.getSheetByName(objectsheetname);
    object.showColumns(5,2);
    object.getColumn(6,1),copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }}}}}}//End of onEdit Functions
```

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCv8cT4rOAfcTOZhzsVzoMntRuHE8v8Cy2j0HmweYqk/edit?usp=sharing)

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function requires an installable trigger.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Internal Audit Register" && e.range.columnStart==7 && isDate(new Date(e.value))) {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    const id=e.range.offset(0,-5).getDisplayValue();
    const osh=e.source.getSheetByName("SOP Register");
    const oshsr=3;
    const org=osh.getRange(oshsr,1,osh.getLastRow()-oshsr+1,osh.getLastColumn());
    const ovs=org.getDisplayValues();
    for(var i=0;i<ovs.length;i++) {
      if(ovs[i][0]==id) {
        osh.getRange(oshsr+i,8).setValue(e.value).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");//you can change the format here
        osh.getRange(oshsr+i,5).setValue("FALSE");
        osh.getRange(oshsr+i,6).setValue("");
        osh.getRange(oshsr+i,7).setValue("");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

It's working.  I tested it.

You can test it with this:

```
function runTwo() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Internal Audit Register");
  const e={};
  e.range=sh.getRange('G1');
  e.value=new Date();
  e.source=ss;
  e.range.columnStart=7;
  onMyEdit(e);
}
```

and you can create a trigger with these:

```
function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  createOnEditTriggerForSpreadsheet('onMyEdit');
}

function createOnEditTriggerForSpreadsheet(funcname) {
  var ssid=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(ssid).onEdit().create();
  }   
}
```

Or you can just test it by using it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not sure if I have added the code and trigger correctly as it is not working. Would you mind having a look at what I have done in the shared spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you create an installable trigger

Comment: Yes - I added the code to my script as a separate function i.e. outside of my current onEdit(e) function. I added the trigger using onMyEdit and made the Event 'From Spreadsheet - On Edit'. I can share the spreadsheet to your email if you prefer.

Comment: Try adding the e.source.toast()'s as I've shown in the script.  Let me which one's display and which don't.

Comment: It errors at const sh=e.range.getSheet(); says cannot read property 'range'

Comment: You of course realize that you can't run an onEdit(e) function without the event object which is placed in the e parameter when an edit trigger occurs.  So the correct way to debug this is to either use another function to call the onMyEdit() function and before making the call create the event object in your code or simply generate the appropriate edit from the appropriate sheet and range.

Comment: Don't know how to do what?

Comment: I don't know how to do either of those things

Comment: You can create an onEdit() trigger by going to edit/current project trigger and selecting addTrigger and the find 'onMyEdit' function name and for spreadsheet and type onedit and save

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213743/discussion-between-cooper-and-mcchief).